# overlapped when i minimize the screen

Tags: html, css

When i make the screen size smaller then the button and select option is getting overlapped as per the snippet. Inbetween the button and the select option there should be a inch gap (This output is coming when the screen is in maximized). can someone please help in this, should i add anything else for the output. Posting the html and css code below:

css:

```css
 body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #262626;
    }
    
    h3
    {
        text-align: right;
        color: #C0C0C0;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
    .box {
        position: absolute;
        top:40%;
        left: 60%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .box1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 60%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .box2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 60%;
        left: 60%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .box select {
        background: #a9a9a9; 
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 35px;
        border: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -webkit-appearance: border;
        outline: none;
    }
    
    .box1 select {
        background: #a9a9a9; 
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 35px;
        border: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -webkit-appearance: border;
        outline: none;
    }
    
    .box2 select {
        background: #a9a9a9; 
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 35px;
        border: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -webkit-appearance: border;
        outline: none;
    }
    
    .ssystem
    {
        position: absolute;
        top:40%;
        left: 41%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        background: #a9a9a9; 
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 35px;
        border: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -webkit-appearance: border;
        outline: none;
    }
    
    .sub
    {
        position: absolute;
        top:50%;
        left: 41%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        background: #a9a9a9; 
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 35px;
        border: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -webkit-appearance: border;
        outline: none;
    }
    
    .subsub
    {
        position: absolute;
        top:60%;
        left: 41%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        background: #a9a9a9; 
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 35px;
        border: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -webkit-appearance: border;
        outline: none;
    }
    
    
    #button
    {
        background: #a9a9a9;
        color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        height:30px;
        width:84px;
        left:63%;
        top:70%;
        border: none;
        color: arial;
        font-size: 16px;
    
    }
    #button:hover
    {
        background: red;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<body style="background-image: url(./img/bkgrnd.png);background-size: cover;">
    <h3>welcome user!!</h3>
    <button class="ssystem">System</button>
    <button class="sub">Sub-System</button>
    <button class="subsub">Sub-Sub-System</button>
    <div class="box" id="sys">
        <select>
            <option>AAA</option>
            <option>BBB</option>
            <option>CCC</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="box1" id="sub">
        <select>
            <option>AAA</option>
            <option>BBB</option>
            <option>CCC</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="box2" id="sub1">
        <select>
            <option>AAA</option>
            <option>BBB</option>
            <option>CCC</option>
        </select>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button">
</body>
```

Comment: why are you applying CSS to every element separately? and you are making the `position: absolute` add come common classes and the write CSS. for every element having appearance need to to write CSS separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rightnow no button is together with a select field and each element is positioned individually independent of each other sibling element. Sibling elements in this case are each button and the divs in which you find the select fields.

You can put the right button together with the right select field, this means you wrap them with a div and apply **display: flex** so they are positioned next to each other. For spacing you can add margin or padding.

Comment: thank you so much for the help. Also for the background if i minimize , two images are getting displayed.